# Symfony and mechanize

Tags: python, symfony1, mechanize

I am trying to access to a local website designed with the Symfony framework.
It works perfectly with the web browser and with CURL but when I use Mechanize I always got the 401 unauthorized answer for the server.

```
import mechanize


# Browser
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_debug_http(True)
br.set_debug_redirects(True)
br.set_debug_responses(True)

# Does not change anything even if we change thos
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

# Here is my website
r = br.open('http://localhost:8080/frontend_dev.php/home')
html = r.read()

# Show the html source 
print html
```

Do you have any idea why it behaves like this?

Thanks

Comment: Is Symfony hit or not? What happens it you write die("hit"); on top of the frontend_dev.php file?

Comment: If I do die("hit"); I see the hit and no 401 error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found the answer by myself.
There is a bug in the sfDoctrineGuardPlugin (and sfGuardPlugin) that causes this behavior as stated [here](http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/4474).
I applied the patch and the problem is solved.

Comment: It's an old bug, I think you must have an old version of the plugin. Consider updating.

Comment: The bug has been corrected in august this year. And the last release of sfDoctrineGuard has been done is 2010. I don't think that you are right. What do you suggest: http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin

Comment: <troll>I suggest to use Symfony2</troll> Seriously, I don't know why the last release is so old... perhaps jwage is too busy with doctrine2 / sf2 ...

Answer (score 1):

there are tight controls on who can access the development environment in symfony. Try using the main URL (probably http://localhost:8080/index.php/home)

Comment: It didn't solved the issue. I just tried it and got the same error

Comment: Sorry. I assume you cleared your cache? Do you have any credentials or anything required?

Comment: For the cache: yes. I don't have any credential needed for the home page, for some pages afterwards yes. And it works perfectly with curl, I don't know why...

Comment: Thank you for helping anyway. It doesn't change anything whetherthe app is in production or not.

Answer (score 1):

Can you refer some valid address to try your code? 
I *guess* that you missed some settings, try to disable robots.

```
br.set_handle_robots(False)
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't change anything.
No I can't provide a valid address to try my code right no (sorry maybe later).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about Symfony framework, but as you are getting `'Error : 401 '` . Adding these lines might work .

```
br.add_password('http://localhost:8080/frontend_dev.php/home', 'username', 'password')
br.open('http://localhost:8080/frontend_dev.php/home')
```

Answer (score 1):

please see http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/4474